# service is running after calling stopService

Tags: android, service

i am learning how to deal with services..i created a small example. the mainActivity sends an integer to the service and the service uses that integer
as the maximum iteration in a loop as shown below in the code.

the problem is when i call stopService(intent) i still receive value from the loop in the service class posted below..i think when i call 
stopService() the service will be destroyed

why that is hapenning?

**service**:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

private final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
final static String MY_ACTION = "MY_ACTION";

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.w(TAG, "onCreate");

    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.w(TAG, "onStartCommand");

    int max = intent.getIntExtra("MAX", -1);
    Log.v(TAG, "Act->Service : " + max);

    MyThread myThread = new MyThread();
    myThread.start();

    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    Log.w(TAG, "onBind");

    return null;
}

class MyThread extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1500);
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(MY_ACTION);
                intent.putExtra("value", i);
                sendBroadcast(intent);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        stopSelf();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: you have to wait at least until your thread completes its run method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when i call stopService(intent) i still receive value from the loop in the service class posted below

Correct. That is because the thread is still running.

> i think when i call stopService() the service will be destroyed

It is. That does not magically cause your thread to stop. You started the thread; you need to stop it, perhaps in `onDestroy()`.